# Why a NUMBER field with a null value is obtained as 0 from Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, oracle10g, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with retrieving `Integer` values from database. I am using Spring Data JPA to interact with the database. For a `NUMBER` column which is nullable, the NULL value from Database (Oracle) is getting back as `0`, instead of `null`.

Here is the code:

`PaymentSpecVO.java`:

```
public class PaymentSpecVO extends BaseVO<PaymentSpec> {
   private Integer paymStartWk;

  public Integer getPaymStartWk() {
  return paymStartWk;
 }
 public void setPaymStartWk(Integer paymStartWk) {
    this.paymStartWk = paymStartWk;
 }
}
```

`PaymentSpecUIService.java`

```
public class PaymentSpecUIService implements IPaymentSpecUIService {

    @Autowired
    protected IPaymentSpecService paymentSpecService;

    public void savePaymentSpec(PaymentSpecVO paymentSpecVO) {
       //some logic
        paymentSpec = paymentSpecService.save(paymentSpec);

       // transform the saved entity back to VO object
       //Here All my VO objects extends BaseVO 
        paymentSpecVO.toDTO(paymentSpec);
    }
  public PaymentSpecVO findPaymentSpecByKey(PaymentSpecId key) {

    //Here during retrival It uses findByKey(key);
    PaymentSpec paymentSpec = paymentSpecService.findByKey(key);
    PaymentSpecVO paymentSpecVO = new PaymentSpecVO();

       if (paymentSpec != null) {
         paymentSpecVO.toDTO(paymentSpec);
         return paymentSpecVO;
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseVO.java**

```
public abstract class BaseVO<E extends Object> implements Serializable {
    private Class<E> entity;

    protected BaseVO(Class<E> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
        ConvertUtils.register(dateConverter, Date.class);
    }

    public Object toDTO(E entity) {

    try {
        copyEntityToValueObjectProperties(entity, this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
      return this;
     }


  /**
  * Copies the properties from Entity object to Value object.
  * 
  * */

    public void copyEntityToValueObjectProperties(Object entityObject, Object valueObject) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException,InstantiationException, SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {

    // Get the list of fields from source objects
    Field[] entityObjectFields = entityObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    // Reference of BaseEntity class type
    Class<?> entityType = BaseEntity.class;
    Class<?> collType = Collection.class;

    // Iteration of entity properties
    for (Field entityField : entityObjectFields) {
        try{
            //
            // Checks whether the entity field is an object and is of type
            // BaseEntity class.
            //
            if (!entityType.isAssignableFrom(entityField.getType()) && !collType.isAssignableFrom(entityField.getType()) 
                 && !Modifier.isFinal(entityField.getModifiers()) && !Modifier.isStatic(entityField.getModifiers())) {
                 BeanUtils.setProperty(valueObject, entityField.getName(), BeanUtils.getProperty(entityObject, entityField.getName()));

            }
          }
          catch(Exception e){
            continue;
         }
       }
    }
```

}

**PaymentSpecId.java**

```
public class PaymentSpecId implements BaseEntity {
  private String contractId;
  private String sectionId;
  private String id;

  public PaymentSpecId() {
  }

  public PaymentSpecId(String id, String contractId, String sectionId){
    this.id = id;
    this.contractId = contractId;
    this.sectionId = sectionId;
  }

  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 2)
  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
   this.id = id;
  }
}
```

`IPaymentSpecService.java`

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface IPaymentSpecService  {
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public PaymentSpec save(PaymentSpec PaymentSpec);
}
```

My DB Table

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE    NULLABLE    DEFAULT_VALUE
------------     ---------    --------    -------------
PAYM_START_WK    NUMBER(4,0)    Yes             null
```

And when I click on edit link from UI i.e., JSF page, its passes paymentID to findPaymentSpecByKey(PaymentSpecId key) method of PaymentSpecUIService.java by using backing beans PaymentSpecVO.java and In popup it will display paymStartWK value in inputText component as 0, though the data in DB is stored as NULL

Comment: @ JB Nizet: please look into my edits.

Comment: You should show how you retrieve data from DB, not how you save data in DB. The problem is in retrieving data from DB. You said that the value is `NULL` in DB, so saving part is completely fine and therefore completely irrelevant to the problem. I eliminated the confusing JSF part from the question. Just concentrate on the problem of retrieving data from DB.

Comment: By the way, after inspection of method names, this code seems to be purely about saving the data. You should edit your question to show code responsible for retrieving the data (including relevant configuration).

Comment: @BalusC Please find my edits.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the hint, finally figured out than the BeanUtils I used does treat Integer as int and mess with NULL to be 0, after adding                               IntegerConverter converter = new IntegerConverter(null); 
  ConvertUtils.register(converter, Integer.class);      in BaseVO Constructor, solves my problem.